# REGEX - Count Number of Occurrences Ignoring Escaped Characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext

My data looks like this: [No Empty Lines]

> Number;Lastname or Company;Firstname;City;Postcode;Amount;
>
> 1;Trump;Donald;Washington;12345;4;
>
> 2;Bush;George;Washington;54321;1;
>
> 3;Lloyds\; and Firends;;11111;2;
>
> 4;Schuhmacher\;Frenzen\;Fettel; and Co;Company;Anywhere;22222;3;
>
> 5;Best\;Friends;Company\;Co;Nowhere;33333;4;

I am trying to validate this csv file by looking for lines that do not have 6 entries per row. I am doing this by counting the number of `;` per line. The only catch is `\;` (escaped semicolon) should not be counted.

This is how I am doing it right now:

1. STEP 1

   - Find= `\\;`
   - Replace= `\s`
2. STEP 2

   - Find= `^([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)$`
   - This will select all correct rows.[ In above case: All rows except 3: and 4:]

PROBLEM is this requires changing the data using substitution. Is there a way to do this with only regex and NO substitution.

I am basically struggling with the part where I have to ignore this pattern `\;`.

EDIT 1: I am using SUBLIME text editor. 
EDIT 2: I have updated the sample text file with `\;`

Comment: Which language are you using? Is it just some raw text in sublime editor ?

Comment: Probably, you need to replace `[^;]*` with `(?:[^;\\]|\\.)*` or `[^\\;]*(?:\\.[^\\;]*)*`

Comment: Yes, its a plain csv.file that I am working on in Sublime Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need substitutions if you consider matching escaped characters individually:

```
(?m)^(?:[^\\;\r\n]*(?:\\.[^\\;\r\n]*)*;){6}$
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/nAz6je/2)

Breakdown:

- `(?m)` Set multiline flag
- `^` Assert beginning of line
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group 1

  - `[^\\;\r\n]*` Match any thing except `\` `;` `\r` and `\n`
  - `(?:` Start of NCG 2

    - `\\.[^\\;\r\n]*` Match an escaped char and repeat matching recent character class
  - `)*` As many as possible
  - `;` Match a semi-colon
- `){6}` Six times exactly
- `$` Assert end of line

Comment: This works great and I understand the logic. Is there a way to select all rows that DO NOT match the above pattern. i.e select 3: and 4: instead of all the rest.

Comment: i know for Linux you can use `grep -v`, I am not sure how to do it in sublime editor.

Comment: Thinking about it another way would be: select all rows NOT equal to 6 semicolon.

Comment: @urwaCFC Yes, luckily you can in sublimetext. Check this  demo https://regex101.com/r/Qg7gUe/1

Comment: I tried `(?!...)` but it did not work. Using `(*F)` seems to solve that.

Comment: `(*SKIP)` is a backtracking verb, it makes engine to start matching process right from where its cursor is and forget what have been matched so far. This verb triggers when a backtracking happens. `(*F)` which literally means `(?!)` always results in a failure which causes a backtrack. Pair verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` are mostly used to remove unwanted results after matching them off the output.. This lets other side of alternation `.+` match remaining parts. Only available in PCRE. @urwaCFC

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "|" in the regex not working?

e.g. `^([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)|\\;$`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what language your are using, but personally i thing you better use a split() follow by count() function. this is available in many languages.

Hope that's helps